# add_index migration fails with "Argument out of range"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to duplicate a (working!) Rails 3/MySql application on another computer. I created a schema.rb and data.yml, then used db:schema:load and db:data:load, and it all worked perfectly except for one thing. I had a number of indexes on my tables, and rake fails trying to create them--I had to comment them out of schema.rb to get it to generate, so I tried putting them into a migration (the way they were created in the original app!) and rake still died. Here's the error message:

```
O:\Development\myapp>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

argument out of range

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:446:in `utc'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:446:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:446:in `indexes'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:406:in `index_name_exists?'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:343:in `add_index'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:359:in `block in say_with_time'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:294:in `measure'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:359:in `say_with_time'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:379:in `method_missing'O:/Development/codenotes/db/migrate/20110114212538_add_notes_index.rb:11:in `up'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:312:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:294:in `measure'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:312:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:537:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:613:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:613:in `ddl_transaction'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:536:in `block in migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:523:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:523:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:433:in `up'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:415:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:142:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
C:/Ruby/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Here is the offending migration:

```
class AddNotesIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
        add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
        add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
        add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
        add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
        remove_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
        remove_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
        remove_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
        remove_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
  end
end
```

This is exactly the same code I used to create the indexes in the original app. As far as I can tell, I'm running exactly the same environment on this computer-- Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3, mysql2 0.2.6 x86-mingw32, MySQL 5.1.41. I even copied over the same libmysql.dll. I'm stumped.

**EDIT**

Haha, I'm stupid. I was updating the libmysql.dll in the MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin but not the one in Ruby\bin. Once I copied the latest version into Ruby\bin, everything worked fine. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Can you open up a DB console (`rails db`) and run `SHOW KEYS FROM users`?  What's the output?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a lot of people have this problem, me included. The error seems to originate from the mysql2 gem. So what worked for me was:

1. Install mysql gem
2. Change from mysql2 to mysql in Gemfile
3. Change adapter from mysql2 to mysql in database.yml

And then possible drop the last table created if it were created in the same migration as the call to add_index since it will try to create it once again.

Perhaps more of a workaround then a solution but I have not encountered any better way yet.